# How to call another function in the "static main" method?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner of C# and I would like to call a function namely `SetTimer()` in the `static void Main()` but it gave some errors as `SetTimer(11, 48, 00);` and `SetTimer(11, 35, 40);` below. Actually, it might work well in a Form vice versa with the `Main()` function. I got so confused about how and when to use these types:

- public void
- static void
- public static void
- private static void
- void

---

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SetTimerAlert
{
    public class Program
    {
        int count = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());

            RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

            //Application.Run(new Form1());
            if (rkApp.GetValue("SetTimerAlert") == null)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else
            {
                SetTimer(11, 48, 00);
                SetTimer(11, 35, 40);
            }
        }

        public void SetTimer(int hh, int mm, int ss)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, hh, mm, ss);
            TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);

            if (DateTime.Now < dt)
            {
                var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null,
                    //other occurrences every 24 hours
                                dt - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
            }
        }

        public void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                //rkApp.SetValue("SetTimerAlert", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Please run programs.");
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hey! I did not see the program runs. Your computer will be shut down for 15 seconds.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate an object. Call instance methods upon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only use static members of a class (e.g. properties, methods etc.), or you don't use any members of a class - make the method static.
Else it has to be non-static.
`private` means it can't be accessed outside the class, so if you don't mean to use it outside the class - make it private
`void` means the method doesn't return anything.
So in your case since `SetTimer` doesn't return anything it has to be `void`, since it doesn't use any class members, it can be `static`, and if you don't plan to use it outside of the class, you can make it `private`.
So you method signature should be:

```
public static void SetTimer(int hh, int mm, int ss)
```

Again, unless it's not invoked from outside the class, in which case it should be:

```
private static void setTimer(int hh, int mm, int ss)
```

Note: naming conventions dictates that private methods' names begin with non-capital letter

Since `SetTimer` uses both `count` and `ProcessTimerEvent`, you should make both of them `static` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your definition about these types. In this case, how can I call `public void SetTimer(int hh, int mm, int ss) { ... }` from the `SetTimer(11, 48, 00);`?

Comment: Edited. Don't change invocation, change the method signature

Comment: After changing the `public` to `static`, I got an error with `int count = 0`, `count == 0` and `count++`. It shows an error as `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SetTimerAlert.Program.count'`

Comment: right.. I didn't notice ProcessTimerEvent was invoked from SetTimer

Answer (score 0):

Both the Timer and the method SetTimer must also be static if being invoked by the static method "Main". Instance methods of the class cannot be invoked by static methods, but an instance can invoke the static method.

Comment: Wrong.  Better: "A `static` method has no `this` instance to implicitly use when calling instance methods; they can only be used by providing an instance"

Comment: True, but how is what I said wrong...? You merely added to the explanation.

Comment: You said that instance methods can't be invoked by static methods of the same class.  They CAN be invoked if an instance is provided.  For example, operator overloads are static methods, but they certainly do access instance methods, properties, and fields of the operands.